# Why set/map emplace_hint does not return a boolean

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace_hint), both `std::set` and `std::map` `emplace` functions return a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, with a `bool` value to say if the insertion actually took place.

However, `emplace_hint` returns an `iterator` either to the inserted element or to the existing element in the set or map if the insertion didn't happen. There is no `bool` value here.

Is there any reason for this difference in the interface of these similar functions?

**Update**

Function `insert` returns the `bool` value only when no hint is provided. This is consistent with the behavior of `emplace` and `emplace_hint`. The question is then: is there any reason to not return a `bool` when a hint is given?

I can only think that maybe there is some performance reason, because the user usually provides a hint after a `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` operation, so it's sure the insertion will happen.

Comment: If a hint is provided for insertion, be it insert or emplace_hint only iterator is returned(No bool for status), So this behavior is quite consistent

Comment: That's true. I'll update my question.

Comment: It's possible the hinted functions simplify the return for efficiency. `emplace_hint` is intended for use in cases where you know where to perform the insertion, and if used correctly, is effectively a `O(1)` operation, rather than `O(log2(n))`. When you're spending `O(log2(n))`, the incremental cost of constructing and returning the pair is small (relatively), but if you're intentionally using the hyperoptimized approach that gives you `O(1)`, you may not want that (admittedly small) overhead. It gives back an `iterator` so you can check the contents (or just compare `size` before and after).

Comment: That said, efficiency is just a guess. Pre-C++11, depending on implementation and compiler, the incremental cost of returning an object like `std::pair<iterator, bool>` could be significantly higher than just returning the `iterator`. Matters less in C++11 (where named locals can be returned by direct construction into their caller, as opposed to copy-constructing and destructing), but `emplace_hint` probably followed the lead of the earlier hinted functions, which pre-dated C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`emplace_hint` does that likely for consistency with the hinted `insert`:  `emplace` was [initially proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2268.pdf) as a pair of overloads, mirroring `insert`, but the hinted overload was renamed after [LWG 763](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-closed.html#763), although Josuttis wanted to [rename the non-hinted version](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-closed.html#1302) instead)

The hinted `insert` for associative containers takes an iterator and a value and returns an iterator in order to be compatible with the regular `insert` on sequential containers in generic code. as mentioned in Josuttis's book. This compatibility is exploited by [std::inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to determine, whether the emplace took place or not, is to store the `size()` of the map in a variable and test, whether that size has increased after the `emplace_hint()`:

```
auto oldsz = myMap.size();
myMap.emplace_hint(it, args...);
if(myMap.size() > oldsz) {
    // emplace was accepted
} else {
    // the emplace was rejected, as it would have overwritten an element
}
```

The same code can also be used with `insert_or_assign()`, if the new value shall overwrite the old in case of an already existing key.

Comment: also, map::size() runs in Constant time, in case you're concerned about performance.